# Calling PostgreSQL stored procedure from Django returns 'invalid input syntax for integer' error - how to solve?

Tags: python, sql, django, stored-procedures

I have this procedure that generates a pdf file with reports from a database. The procedure itself works well. The issue is, when I try to call it from my django application, it doesn't work.

```
cursor.callproc("fun_servidores_folha", 
    (self.storage.entidade.id,
        self.storage.folha.id,
        self.request['agrupamento'],
        'completo',
        self.filtros.get('vinculo__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('lotacao__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('und_trab_1__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('und_trab_2__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('cargo__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('funcao__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('marca__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('cargo__marca__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('und_trab_1__marca__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('lotacao__marca__in', []),
        self.filtros.get('id__in', [])))
```

I get the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT:  função PL/pgSQL fun_servidores_folha(integer,integer,text,text,text[],text[],text[],text[],text[],text[],text[],text[],text[],text[],text[]) linha 621 em RETURN QUERY
```

When debugging, for example, I can try `(1, 1, 'lotacao', 'completo', [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [])` but it returns the error I mentioned above.

Here is the beginning of the procedure file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fun_servidores_folha(
    entidade_id integer,
    folha_id integer,
    agrupamento text,
    relatorio text,
    vinculo__in text[],
    lotacao__in text[],
    und_trab_1__in text[],
    und_trab_2__in text[],
    cargo__in text[],
    funcao__in text[],
    marca__in text[],
    cargo__marca__in text[],
    und_trab_1__marca__in text[],
    lotacao__marca__in text[],
    id__in text[])
```

So I'm stuck with this.